# Proving that the magnetic force experienced by a charged particle produces a circular motion

Tags: electromagnetism, forces

I have a charged particle $q=-1$, $m=1$, moving with a velocity $\mathbf{v} = <\dot{x},\dot{y},0>$, under the influence of a magnetic field $\mathbf{B} = < 0,0,-B>$, where $B > 0$.

I want to know what the equation of motion is and why is it that books equate $qvB\sin \theta = \dfrac{mv^2}{r}$. Since books equate it to $\dfrac{mv^2}{r}$, then the charged particle must be moving in a circle.

I used $\mathbf{F} = q\mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{B}$. I ended up having $\begin{cases} \ddot{x} = \dot{y}B \\ \ddot{y} = -\dot{x}B \end{cases}$. I am stuck and I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't really take into account the fact that the vectorial product of the velocity and the magnetic field appears in your expression.

In general, from Newton's equation, you can rightfully write

$$ m \frac{\partial^2 \pmb{r}}{\partial t} = q \frac{\partial \pmb{r}}{\partial t} \times \pmb{B} $$

Assuming that the magnetic field is constant in time, that is, $\pmb{B}(t) = B$, you can write

$$ m \frac{\partial^2 \pmb{r}}{\partial t} = q \frac{\partial r}{\partial t} B \sin(\theta) \pmb{\hat{n}} \, $$

where we use the normal vector $\pmb{\hat{n}}$ to set the direction of motion according to the right hand rule. This then means that the acceleration vector will always be perpendicular to the velocity vector: this is the definition of a circular motion.

Now all you need to do is plug in your specific vector components from the exercise to find the radius of this circular path.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to show this.

The first one is more simple: by observing the only external force on the particle is always tangent to its velocity, there is no tangential acceleration, so the magnitude of the velocity $|\vec{v}|$ is always the same. Also, the magnitude of axial acceleration ${|\vec{F}| \over m}$ is always the same since the speed of the particle does not change. Therefore, the particle follows circular motion.

The second solution is solving the equation of motion directly. Since $\ddot{x}=\dot{y}B$, $\dddot{x}=\ddot{y}B$. Replacing it with $\ddot{y}$ in the second equation you derive, we have
$$\dddot{x} = -B^2 \dot{x}$$
The solution to this equation is $\dot{x}(t)=\cos{(Bt+\phi)}v_0$ where $v_0$ and $\phi$ are some constants. Therefore, $\dot{y}(t)=-\sin{(Bt+\phi)}v_0$. You can now determine $v_0$ and $\phi$ with the initial condition. Also, by integrating $\dot{x}(t)$ and $\dot{y}(t)$ over $t$, you will find the trajectory of $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ is a circle, with the condition that $|\dot{x}(t)|^2+|\dot{y}(t)|^2=v_0^2$, which is a constant, the motion of the particle is uniform circular motion.